# Display post image with fancybox

Tags: php, images

I am trying to display the image with fancybox, but the code shows an empty href which is causing me problems with fancybox.

What is wrong in this kind of code? it's showing up the correct image url, but not where I put it. I would like the src to be in href too.

This is my php code

```
echo "<a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='".the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' )."'>";
```

and this is my output:

```
<div class="white-block-media">
                                http://myurl.com/image.jpg
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="">
<img width="600" height="848" src="http://myurl.com/image.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt=""></a>                      
    </div>
```

Comment: Where are you using this code, is it inside [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you echo something, you need to be echoing the variable.  You are using the_post_thumbnail_url, which in itself is already an echo statement.  You should be using [get_the_post_thumbnail_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) instead.

```
echo "<a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='" . get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' ) . "'>";
```

EDIT: Also, missing the $post_id, fixed to include it in the function

Comment: thanks! but I still get my href blank, any clue what it could be?

Comment: oh I found that removing 'full' it works! maybe something wrong with ' ' in that code

Comment: Yeah, I should've gotten that too, the reason being is that you need to pass two properties, $post_id & $size, I'll change my answer to be correct